Should a CPE ID be prepended with the "URN:" schema?
To my knowledge, all URNs ultimately utilize the URN schema, which means that it must be prefixed for the URI to be valid. However, the current CPE ID within Fedora 41 KDE Spin (with an equivalent in openSUSE Tumbleweed 20241129) /etc/os-release is:
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:41"

If I am correct, it should instead be:
CPE_NAME="urn:cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:41"

Have I instead misread RFC 8141?

The assignment of URNs is done by an organization (or, in some cases, according to an algorithm or other automated process) that has been formally delegated a URN namespace within the "urn" scheme (e.g., a URN in the "example" URN namespace [RFC6963] might be of the form "urn:example:foo").

(Lack of) Duplicates
Previously asked at discussion.fedoraproject.org, to no response (yet).

CPE names aren't URNs, so they aren't subject to RFC 8141. In version 2.2 of the CPE specification, they were defined as stand-alone URIs with cpe: being the top-level URI scheme.
Per RFC 3986 §1.1.3 and W3C, there is no longer a strict division of URIs between "URN" and "URL"; there can be URI schemes other than urn: that are not locators.
In version 2.3 the CPE name is defined more abstractly, with multiple string representations possible, but os-release(5) specifies that CPE_NAME should continue to use the CPE2.2-compatible "URI binding syntax" of the CPE name.

What a mess. Thanks. I believed that the at least, sole immutable differentiator between URNs and URLs (both being URIs, but with all URNs utilizing the URN: schema/namespace, as Wikipedia corroborates) was that URNs do not point to a location. They are merely identifiers. URIs, in contrast, URLs always direct to a location. Consequently, how can a CPE ID not be a URN?

First, that's a false dichotomy – according to the definition in RFC 3986, all URIs are not required to be "either a URL or a URN" but can also be simply URIs without a more specific classification.

Second, your logic seems to be based on the 'historical use' definition in RFC 3986, i.e. that "URNs are either a) URIs under the 'urn:' scheme or b) any other URI with properties of a name", but the problem is that you first claim that "cpe: URIs are URNs(b)" under case b) and then immediately forget case b) exists and try to claim that "if they are URNs(a) then they must have the urn: scheme" as if the same definition only had case a) – which doesn't follow because they are URNs(b), not URNs(a).

Many thanks, @grawity. Also, apologies for the duplicated words and spelling mistakes in that comment. I wrote it late at night.
